# Attempting to Update with Yum through Terminal Fails

Tags: fedora, yum, fedora-22

Since upgrading to Fedora 22, I have had an issue with updating using `yum` through the Terminal. Whenever I run the `sudo yum update` command, this happens every time:

[image: 'sudo yum update' Fails]

What's the matter? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search /etc/yum.repos.d directory for https repositories - normally repositories are configured to use http (this is secure, as all packages are signed). Disable http repositories, if they have http equivalents.

Also you can execute (as root):

```
update-ca-trust
```

This may or may not help, depending on repository server configuration - the above error doesn't give 100% sure, that its configuration isn't simply broken.

Comment: None of the above worked. Did you mean remove http equivalents?

Comment: Never mind, it is fixed. `metalink` values in `fedora.repo` and `fedora-updates.repo` used `https`. Changing them to `http` seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are  attempting to use yum on fedora 22 which is  no longer supported in that fashion  use yumex-dnf OR  take the "NEW" proper  way  sudo dnf update

```
 sudo dnf clean all
 sudo  dnf update 
 sudo  OR su -c 'update-ca-trust'  ## only run if  the dnf update  fails to  update it in the previous step..  Also  check for  drops in connectivity  as the  second error can also happen with  landing pages and  spotty connects...
```

Comment: Could that have something to do with the problem that I was having? I know that `yum` is deprecated as of Fedora 22, but I do not know if that would be the cause of the problem I am having.

Comment: the first warning is that ( the redirect to dnf) the second is  either 1) outdated and unreacheable MD OR  a bad cert which the  sudo (or su -c)  update-ca-trust will fix